# Subconcultas en Laravel 5.*

Tags: sql, laravel-5, postgresql, subconsultas

Estoy intentando correr una subconsulta dentro de un controlador de laravel 5 sin utilizar modelos, siempre he ocupado eloquent, pero hasta el momento no había requerido realizar una subconsulta nativa de sql.

La subconsulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR (f.fechas, 'dd')as Dias,
TO_CHAR (f.fechas, 'HH12')as Horas,
TO_CHAR (f.fechas, 'MI')as Minutos, 
TO_CHAR (f.fechas, 'SS') as Segundos
FROM
(select (now()-Loaded_on)as fechas
from p02_issste WHERE folio_p01 = '04815-2011-1B2EA')as f
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: La subconsulta me va perfecto en el gestor de DB, al correrlo el explorador me dice que falta una coma (,), revisé un poco por foros de desarrollo y trato de realizar la consulta con DB::select('...') y me arroja el explorador el siguiente error: syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: He cambiado las comillas simples por comillas dobles y al parecer se soluciona pero marca el siguiente error:
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: el operador no existe: timestamp with time zone - character varying LINE 7: (select (now()-Loaded_on)as fechas ^ HINT: Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos. (42883)